# Need help proving the following for every integer n larger or equal to 1

Tags: discrete-mathematics

i need help proving the following :
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{(3k-1)(3k+2)}=\frac{n}{6n+4}$$ for every integer n larger or equal to 1

Can you help? Thanks

Comment: should this better be in math stackexchange?

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{(3k-1)(3k+2)}=\frac{1}{3}\sum_{k=1}^{n}[\frac{1}{3k-1}-\frac{1}{3k+2}]=
\frac{1}{3} \{[\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{11}+\frac{1}{14}.........+\frac{1}{3n-1}]-[\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{11}+\frac{1}{14}.........+\frac{1}{3n-1}+\frac{1}{3n+2}]\}=\frac{1}{3}[\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3n+2}]=\frac{n}{6n+4}$$